# How to animate an element when scrolled and reveals

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to Animate an Element when part of it or completely reveals after scrolled to its position. The code I am using do that action when scrolled to a absolute position (not the position of the object).

The animation I used is SlideUp. I haven't any idea for write a code to do that. I want a little help to write that code. Can anyone present the method (better with a small example) of writing that?

Code is below:

```js
function reveal() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 350 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 350) {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").className = "slideUp";
  }
}
```

```css
/* When Class changed to slideUp, Animation will start */

.slideUp {
  animation-name: slideUp;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideUp;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  visibility: visible;
}

@keyframes slideUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Div has absolutely positioned to avoid showing when page load first time|Because, User should scroll to it for animate it. -->
<div id="myDiv" style="position:absolute;top:1500px;left:1px;">
  <p>Example text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why dont you use wow.js and animate.css combination. It works great for this purpose. Head to there docs for better understanding.

Comment: I dont really understand what you are trying ti achive. What element and what behavior are you looking for?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO I am trying to animate DIV element when user see it. The most codes i tried are animating when the page loads. When user see the Element, Animation has finished. So i am trying to animate when user scrolls to it.

Comment: @void I will try. Give me some mins to search and know.

Comment: @void It must be the Answer. Thank you So much for helping me! I hope you will post that as an answer. I have seen wow before, But i haven't understood it as a method to 'scroll reveal'. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To animate an element when it reveals on scroll, [wow.js](https://wowjs.uk/docs) is the best resource combined with [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Basic example to do so:

```
<div class="wow bounceInUp">
    Content to Reveal Here
</div>
```

Do not forget to initialize it.

```
<script>
    new WOW().init();
</script>
```